# How to specify c++ system include path in Eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse

GCC has the option -isystem to treat the directories as system directory so that compile warning is not generated for these directories. However I couldn't find similar settings in Eclipse (I am using Mars 2 Release 4.5.2). Have tried checking "Contains system header" when adding "include Directory" in "Project properties"/"C/C++ General"/Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc."/"CDT User Setting Entries" but doesn't help. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncheck the **CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings** in
**Project Properties** / **C/C++ General** / **Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc** / **Providers**
And add your own include path in
**C/C++ General** / **Paths and Symbols** / **Includes** / **GNU C** or **C++**